# Creating customisable configuration using .NET

Tags: .net, configuration, configurationsection

I'm trying to create some typed configuration similar to the following snippet...

```
<logging application="Global Application Name">
    <defaultLogger name="default" genericOption="XXX" specificOptionYYY="yyy" />
    <defaultLogger name="notAsDefault" genericOption="AAA" specificOptionYYY="bbb" />
    <anotherDefaultLogger name="anotherDefault" genericOption="ZZZ" specificOptionWWW="www" />
</logging>
```

At the root would be a LoggerSettings class that would contain the `application` property and a collection of `LoggingConfigurationElement`s.

The LoggingConfigurationElement would contain the `genericOption` property.
There would then be two specific sub-classes that would be created containing the `specificOptionYYY` and `specificOptionWWW`.

How would I then go about matching and instantiating the correct sub-class of configuration element at run time based on the element's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to override the `OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement` method and dynamically create the configuration element required, and deserialise it manually.

```
override protected bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement (string elementName, System.Xml.XmlReader 
{
    if (sNames.ContainsKey (elementName))
    {
        var elementType = sNames[elementName];
        if (elementType != null)
        {
            var element = Activator.CreateInstance (elementType) as LoggerConfigurationElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.DeserializeElementForConfig (reader, false);
                BaseAdd (element);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return base.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement (elementName, reader);
}
```

In this example, I've pre-built the list of valid element names using a combination of reflection and configuration (yes, more configuration!) so I know up-front if the supplied element is a valid one.